# Scraping from javascript-controlled table in Wayback Machine?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape details from two archived webpages, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121004160735/https://m360.atdc.org/frontend/search.aspx?cs=3433) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130308113650/https://m360.atdc.org/frontend/search.aspx?cs=3223).

As you can see, the content lives in a paginated table (10 records are shown out of 30+) that I believe is being controlled with javascript - if you hover over the right arrows at the bottom of the table, you can see they are advanced through a doPostBack call. Unfortunately, these arrows are non-functional in the archived pages themselves, as is the drop-down that allows you to change the number of visible rows in the table.

Does anyone know how to either (a) get the javascript working to advance the table correctly or (b) gather the information some other way from this webpage? I've attempted to look at the request/response objects as well, but I'm quite a novice with web scraping so there is a good chance I missed something.

Any direction (or being told its a fool's errand!) is helpful, thanks in advance to whoever takes a look!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.